# How do I write the type definition for a module with a default export

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, type-definition, storybook

I want to write a type definition for [`storybook-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/storybook-router). It needn't be that accurate, since this is a minor development tool (i.e. `any`s are acceptable), but I can't even seem to get that to work.

What I want to represent is:

```
import StoryRouter from 'storybook-router';
```

...in which `StoryRouter` is a function that matches the interface `StoryDecorator` from `@types/storybook__react`.

I tried the following definition file:

```
import { StoryDecorator } from '@storybook/react';

declare type StoryRouter = StoryDecorator;

export default StoryRouter;
```

Unfortuantely, that results in the following error:

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'storybook-router'. '/<path snipped>/node_modules/storybook-router/dist/StoryRouter.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>        Try `npm install @types/storybook-router` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'storybook-router';`

However, if I use that final example (`declare module 'storybook-router'`), I can't seem to figure out how to set a default export.

What's the correct way to represent this type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't import in a .d.ts file, you just declare the module.
Usually, it looks like this (simplest use-case with any):

```
// storybook-router.d.ts
declare module 'storybook-router' {
    const StoryDecorator:any;
    export default StoryDecorator;
}
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, that works, and is good enough for me. Out of curiosity, is there a way to get that `any` to actually be the type of `@storybook/react`'s `StoryDecorator`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way to make a definition file for almost any js library. I'm no expert myself tho, and even if, I'd have to read up on that class?, since I have never used it.
My usual approach to create a definition file is to look for libraries, which have type definitions and use a similar approach, then check how they do it.

BTW, I've just found this, which seems like what you are looking for:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/storybook__react

Comment: Try searching https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/ when you are looking for definitions

Comment: Those are type definitions for `@storybook/react`, whereas I'm looking for type definitions for `storybook-router` - which is supposed to _implement_ `StoryDecorator` from the former package...