# How to declare a type that's not a function for a default export

Tags: typescript

I've seen many examples for default exports that only work with functions like [How to declare a type for a default export in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55528921/how-to-declare-a-type-for-a-default-export-in-node-js)

I cannot find a way to do a `.d.ts` file for a JavaScript file that default exports only a data structure, like, an Array. For example:

```
// index.js
const something = {a: 'b'}
export default something
```

```
// index.d.ts
// this fails
interface Something {
  a: string;
};

export default Something;
```

Again, this is for a `index.d.ts` file, the inlining the types (like the example in the lin) in the same file it's trivial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write the type definition for a module with a default export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903313/how-do-i-write-the-type-definition-for-a-module-with-a-default-export)

Comment: It's similar, but my question is not targeting a library, it;s for a local file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

```
// index.d.ts

declare module './index.js' {
  const a: string;
}
```

There's no need to export anything in this case.